# Parse a "list" (as an object) of object as integer-object (hashmap) in JSON using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I have this kind of json:

```
{
 "1": {"id": 1, "first": "mymethod", "second" : [true, true, false]} ,
 "4": {"id": 2, "first": "foo", "second" : [true, true, false]},
 "67": {"id": 67, "first": "bar", "second": [true, true, false]},
 "70": {"id": 70, "first": "foobar", "second" : [true, true, false]}
}
```

I am trying to parse it using gson (using Android) but I cannot for some reason. I have tried a lot of combinations: `HashMaps<Integer, TheClass> ; TheClass[] ; ArrayList<TheClass>` ; etc... but I still not be able to do it!

Everything, of course, using an auxiliary class for the type in the case of generic:

```
public class TheClassList extends whatever<TheClass> {}
```

and

```
gson.fromJson(jsonstr, TheClassList.class);
```

Any help will be appreciated? Thanks a lot.

PS: Note the "index" of each object. It is an integer ever but it isn't consecutive (1,2,99...).

Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Is GSON a requirement? Could http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how you your JSON is a single object with four fields, since there are curly braces {} at the root rather than square brackets []. So any attempt to parse this as a list or an array will not work.

Assuming TheClass is defined as follows:

```
public class TheClass {

    private int id;
    private String first;
    private boolean[] second; // List<Boolean> would work as well

}
```

Then this can be parsed using the following:

```
TypeToken<Map<Integer, TheClass>> token = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, TheClass>>() {};
Map<Integer, TheClass> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonstr, token.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I used a MapHash and I am learn something new of howto pass the ".class" using TypeToken.
Thanks a lot :-). Sorry, I can't vote your answer already.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following library - http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar&can=2&q=